# Not getting the desire record Pearson results

Tags: r, correlation

Any help is greatly appreciated. I did get help with cleaning up the data so it works great that way, no errors. But it's not the same values so I'm not sure where it's wrong. I've tried even running the cor.test a few different ways and don't come up with the right values. It won't allow me to upload the dataset because it isn't local, but it is nycflights13 found here https://nycflights13.tidyverse.org/

Here's my initial code:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(nycflights13))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lm.beta))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(data.table))
Q1 <- (conf.level = 99.45)  #based on Q2 values .. confidence level
delay_thresh = quantile(flights$dep_delay, p=c(0.003, 0.997), na.rm=T)
dist_thresh = quantile(flights$distance,p=c(0.003, 0.997), na.rm=T)
                      
nycflights13_DT <- as.data.table(flights)
nycflights13_clean <- nycflights13_DT[nycflights13_DT$dep_delay > delay_thresh[[1]] & 
                                        nycflights13_DT$dep_delay < delay_thresh[[2]] & 
                                        nycflights13_DT$distance>dist_thresh[[1]] & 
                                        nycflights13_DT$distance < dist_thresh[[2]]]
Q2 <- cor.test(nycflights13_clean$dep_delay, nycflights13_clean$distance)               
model2 = (lm(nycflights13_clean$dep_delay ~ nycflights13_clean$distance))
Q3 <- summary(model2)
```

So then I run:

```
Q2 <- cor.test(nycflights13_clean$dep_delay, nycflights13_clean$distance)               
model2 = (lm(nycflights13_clean$dep_delay ~ nycflights13_clean$distance))
```

This is what I'm supposed to get:

```
t = -14.451, df = 326677, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-0.02870131 -0.02184737
sample estimates:
        cor 
-0.02527463
```

This is what I get:

Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  nycflights13_clean$dep_delay and nycflights13_clean$distance

```
t = -13.647, df = 316421, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-0.02773612 -0.02077163
sample estimates:
       cor 
-0.02425417
```

This is what I'm supposed to be doing:
Run cor.test for the relationship between departure delay and distance. Q2, do not round.
I can do almost anything in Python and NumPy but R has me scratching my head.

Comment: It's tough to help because it's not clear what data cleaning was done, and what accounts for the small discrepancy, but it's almost certainly because some cases were removed, or at least some data was transformed.  It's also not clear on why the `lm()` commands are relevant to your question.

Comment: I tried even off the original data and couldn't get it from that either. Originally, I got errors running lm() that the 2 variables I was running it on weren't even. Thanks though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73652339/im-not-able-to-get-an-even-amount-of-data-to-run-the-cor-test here's a link to my original question where we cleaned up the data. Not sure if that helps. Appreciate you though.

Comment: There must be something else going on. For your issue with `lm()`, given that you are pulling 2 variables from a data frame, it's not logical that you're having an issue of the variable lengths differing.